# Select * syntax changed

Tags: php, mysql, heidisql

Without changing any settings, queries containing backticks like so `` table.`*` ``  no longer work, must be `table.*`

This happened on a production server (MySQL 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log) for no apparent reason.

Why we used backticks: When editing in HeidiSQL and typing `select table.*` it will automatically change it to `` select table.`*` ``  and we've copied it as is into PHP pages.

Query was:

`` select u.`*` from users u ``

Ran fine for years, yesterday (without any changes or upgrades made to either PHP of MySQL, it started giving error: `1054- Unknown column 'u.*' in 'field list`

Replacing the query with the one below solved the problem:

`select u.* from users u`

Interestingly enough, `` u.`field` ``  still works fine.

Comment: Page is not showing what I've typed, should be table . ' * ' (without spaces)

Comment: could you paste the query you used?

Comment: Provide an example of the query text which was executed safely previously, add error message text (full and non-changed) which is produced now for this query execution attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can tell: the change would have needed to be in whatever code you are generating your queries from, which would have possibly been parsing out your single quotes from the table. As far back as at least MySQL 5.4, I can test on a SQLFiddle that this would throw an error, and the syntax wouldn't make much sense in the first place. If you don't have the `table.` prefix, querying a quoted asterisk (`Select '*' FROM table;`) would simply return a single-column list of asterisks the length of the `table`. I do not believe this is a MySQL change.